# Can Magento be used for purchasing and selling products?

Tags: magento-1.9

Our business is buying second hand mobile phones online, repair them and sell them online again.
It´s clear that Magento would do the selling job without any problem but I was wondering if I could also use it for buying phones (separate frontend) by means of an extension or something like that.

Comment: What will be the sellers role? They will sell their second hand products and how they will get paid? Will they ship the product from there end, or a representative from your end will visit the seller after he/she registers the product in your site?

Answer (score 0):

Seem it is NOT so likely.

For user to upload a product, they need to work thru the admin panel.
Even you are willing to give a new ROle public passowrd to allow them to upload their phone info/images, you cannot guarantee the information of other products is safe.

Beside, their is no extension for you to pay to other parties in magento, still you have to pay out of magento.

So, it would be highly ineffective working this way.